# error with shoes no superclass method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing an interface with green_shoes (GUI) for commercials.

Below there is my script to connect to ldap server and check if the user exist, I can enter the login and the password.
When I click on the button "login" with login or without it I get an error.

Error:

```
 may not work as expected
/home/zyriuse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/green_shoes-1.1.374/lib/shoes/ruby.rb:14:in `exit_application': super: no superclass method `exit_application' for GLib:Module (NoMethodError)
        from /home/zyriuse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/green_shoes-1.1.374/lib/shoes/main.rb:123:in `main'
```

**The scripts**

```
require 'green_shoes'
require 'net/ldap'

Shoes.app(:title => "Authentification",:width => 300, :height => 300) do
  class ConnectLdap
  @myApp

  def initialize(myapp, connect = nil)
    @connect = connect
    @myApp = myapp
  end

  def connect(login,pwd)
    @myApp.app do
      ldap = Net::LDAP.new
      ldap.host = "78.110.xx.xx"
      ldap.port = 389
      ldap.auth "cn=admin,dc=domaine,dc=com", "password"

      filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq("uid","#{login}")
      dn = ["dn"]
      @connect = ldap.bind_as(:base => "dc=domaine,dc=com", :filter => filter, :attributes => dn, :password => "#{pwd}")
    end
  end

  def connect?
    if !!@connect == true
      alert "Successful login"
    else
      alert "wrong password or login"
    end
  end

end

stack do
  @myActions = ConnectLdap.new(self)
  para "login"
  login = edit_line

  para "password"
  password = edit_line
  button "login" do
    @myactions.connect(login.text,password,text)
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but I've only now seen it...
Have you tried with green_shoes 1.1.367?

regards,
seba